# How do I align the submenu, aligned with the menu

Tags: css, wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J7Ut.png)
my client's website menu looks like this;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIPes.png)
She would like it to look like this: how do I keep it lined up like this?

The provisional website is at this link: https://clients.rafaelstrabelli.com/

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the width of the `<ul>` menu with `width: 100%` and then use `justify-content: space-between;` to have the `<li>` items spread across the length of the menu.

Comment: I try, but dont work here... you know how i can disable the first and second row's? https://imgur.com/a/9cRls5m after that maybe i can adjust

Comment: The css changes i proposed work for me when i add them directly on your site via the styles editor. As for disabling the first two rows, it seems like you have 3 `.column` divs, the first two are empty (the ones you mentioned). If you just want one, you can always delete the first two and offset the last one with `.offset-lg-8` (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns)